# Slack events: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, regex, list, exception, slack-api

I am trying to read events from slack and return the response for the matching event.

The problem is, when I match an event and return it to slack, it gives me an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code Snippet:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
res = regVal.findall(text)  ### output of res, res = ['CHG1234567']
if res:
    change = res[0]
    incomingSlack(change, channel)
```